# Use $\epsilon, \delta$ to show the function is continuous at $x_0=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

**Q**: Show function is continuous at $x_0=0$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x\sin\frac{1}x & x > 0 \\ x^{1/3} & x \le 0 \end{cases}$$

**Attempt**:

> for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ so that $|x\sin\frac{1}x| < \epsilon$ with $0 < x < \delta$ and these equalities tell us that  $|x\sin\frac{1}x| \le x$ so we choose $\epsilon = \delta$
>
> for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ so that $|x^{1/3}| < \epsilon$ with $ -\delta < x < 0$.....and let $\epsilon = \delta^{1/3}$? I am stuck here. I've only practice cases where $x>0$ so this part confuses me..

Thanks for any response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the right, we see $\left\lvert x \sin\left( \tfrac 1 x \right) \right \rvert \le x$ so if $x > 0$ and $0 < x < \epsilon$, then $\lvert f(x) \rvert <  \epsilon$.

From the left, if $x < 0$ and $0< \lvert x \rvert < \epsilon^3$ gives $\lvert f(x) \rvert = \lvert x^{1/3} \rvert <  \epsilon$.

For fixed $\epsilon > 0$, take $\delta = \min\{\epsilon, \epsilon^3 \}$. Then for $0 < \lvert x \rvert < \delta$, we get $\lvert x \rvert < \epsilon$ and $\lvert x \rvert < \epsilon^3$ so since both inequalities are satisfied, we have $\lvert f(x) \rvert < \epsilon$ which shows that $f$ is continuous at $0$. (All this works since $f(0) = 0$.)

Comment: from the first sentence, do you mean $0< x< \delta$? not $0 < x < \epsilon$?

Comment: No, I mean $\epsilon$. I suppose what I'm really doing there is showing that from the right, it suffices to take $\delta = \epsilon$. Then from the left, it suffices to take $\delta = \epsilon^3$. Thus taking the minimum of these two $\delta$'s works from both sides, so this is the $\delta$ you want to take to satisfy the definition of continuity.

Comment: oh right!! because $\delta = \epsilon$ from the right. So both from the left and right, you SHOWED $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ and that tells function is continuous at $0$?? right?

Comment: Exactly right! Like I said, this works since $f(0) = 0$, so we are proving that for this $\delta$, we have $\lvert f(x) - f(0) \rvert = \lvert f(x) \rvert < \epsilon$.